# How to post/get with asp:Button to another page and with custom data

Tags: asp.net

I have a simple button on the page:

```
            <asp:Button ID="generateIsp" runat="server"
                        style="float: right;"
                        Text="" SkinID="Classic"
                        PostBackUrl="../Handlers/ISPOutput.ashx"  />
```

But **ISPOutput.ashx** handler needs an **input parameter**, let's say **id**. Is there a way to pass that information when **generateIsp** button is clicked ?

I know I could use a link control, but then it will break my layout...

Comment: If it's just layout that you're concerned about, can you use CSS to format the link button to look like a regular button tag?  Do you need `generateIsp` to post data, or are you just looking to get the data into the URL?

Comment: I need to access id in ISPOutput.ashx, doesn't matter whether it is as query string or form data. And yes, I could style it to look like the button, but that is last resort  :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this code - Query String

```
generateIsp.PostBackUrl = "EditUser.aspx?yourParameter=yourValue";


<asp:Button ID="generateIsp" runat="server"
                    style="float: right;"
                    Text="" SkinID="Classic"
                    PostBackUrl="../Handlers/ISPOutput.ashx?yourParameter=yourValue"  />
```